# R corrplot: weird error with significance test

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I am desperately trying to solve an issue with R corrplot. I have a 10 * 22 matrix that I would like to visualize using corrplot, but adding significance level just produces crosses outside of the boarder of the visual. I could produce correlation plots without significant tests using the following script:

```
corrplot(matrix, method = "circle",tl.cex=0.4, tl.col = "black", col = color(10))
```

[image]

However, the following script produces crosses outside of the border of the visual:

```
res1 <- cor.mtest(corredata, conf.level = .95)
corrplot(matrix, p.mat = res1$p, method = "circle", tl.cex=0.6, tl.col = "black", 
         col = color(10), sig.level = 0.05, insig = "pch")
```

[image]

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show how "matrix" and "res1$p" look like in order to reproduce the error.

Comment: I figured it out! Because my matrix was not a square matrix, so I have to remove some rows and columns after generating the correlation matrix. Thank you for your help Karolis